# How to prevent the virtual keyboard from showing on JavaSE build

Tags: codenameone

I tried looking for a way to prevent the virtual keyboard from showing the first time a text field is focused on a JavaSE build but wasn't successful.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code in your init(Object) method to disable that behavior:

```
Display.getInstance().setProperty("javase.win.vkb", "false")
```

This should disable that behavior and only impact windows touch devices.